# Why is typeahead.js/ bloodhound returning "Cannot read property 'whitespace' of undefined"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I've had Twitter Typeahead.js integrated into a Rails app for some time, and working fine.

After a series of gem updates and movement of some dependencies to Bower, I am now seeing an error in the console and Typeahead.js is not being called correctly.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'whitespace' of undefined`

on

`queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace`

What does this mean, and how do I debug this?

My full code:

```
jQuery ->  
  if $('.country-typeahead').length
    countries = new Bloodhound(
      prefetch:
        url: "../api/countries.json"
      datumTokenizer: (datum) ->
        Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace datum.name
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
    )

    countries.initialize()

    $('.country-typeahead').typeahead null,
      name: "countries"
      displayKey: "name"
      source: countries.ttAdapter()
```

The json looks like this

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Aruba"},{"id":2,"name":"Afghanistan":""},{.....etc}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have figured this out already, but since I was having the same issue I thought I would post my solution.

don't use the bloodhound package in Bower and remove any references to that library.   You only need typeahead.js since it includes bloodhound.

Answer (score 0):

include typeahead.bunde.js instead typeahead.js the issue is because missing dependencies .bundle contains all required dependencies